# In Swift, how to make several copies of an object?

Tags: ios, swift, copy, duplicates

I am trying to make several copies of an object to then append into an array. I am converting my object into a NSObject to use the method "copy()", however, I want to have "n" copies of this object instantly and append them all into an existing array. For instance, see below:

```
 var okay = "okay"
 var NSOkay = okay as NSObject
 var copyOkay: AnyObject = NSOkay.copy()

 var array = [String]()
 array.append(copyOkay as! String)
```

However, this will append a unique copy of my item. Lets say, I wish to append 10 copies of the item, how would I then do ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: How about a for loop?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you clarify how to approach this please ? Also, I am afraid that if I need to have for instance thousand copies of the item instantly, this way will take too long, wouldnt it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value types are copied by default (Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)). Other than the obvious for loop way, here is another way of doing the same:

```
import Foundation

//the string
let okay = "okay"
//There is no need to convert a String to NSObject
let NSOkay = okay as NSObject
//number of copies
let n = 3
//pre-existing array
var array : [NSObject] = ["Well", "then"]

array += Array(count: n, repeatedValue: NSOkay) //["Well", "then", "okay", "okay", "okay"]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a million!